# Index creation strategy in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have a foreign key (IdForign), and always use it in where clause.
I have three fields:

```
Id
Name
IdForign
```

How can i create the index for the Name field?
(IdForign, Name) or just one for IdForign and other for Name?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I undertand correctly your question, you need to create an Index only for `IdForign`, because it's the one you use in the `where`

**UPDATE**
As per your comment, if you are using both fields I suggest you to use an index with Name and IdForign

Read [this](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Indexes-in-SQL-Server-20052008-Best-Practices-Part-1.aspx). It should give you some tips on indexing with Sql Server

Comment: Hi, i need the index for Name field, my question is if i have this "where Name='aaa' and IdForign=2" what is better, one index for each field or on index for two fields.

Answer (score 0):

The basic systax, which it seems is all you are asking for is:

```
CREATE INDEX yourIndexName ON yourTableName (yourFieldName);
```

This is also assuming you mean Microsoft SQL Server. See here for the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for the answer.
I know the syntax, i ask for the fields wich i need to use.

Comment: It this is what you were after, great! But remember to be more specific about what your requirements are. This will help you get better answers and more replies.